# Searching for a substring in a String among NULL characters in text file

Tags: c, string, search, replace, null

Hey I wanted to search for a substring 'Step1' in a file and searched it wit my code. Although that file contains NULL characters (mostly HEX characters). With these Null characters in my file, my parser is failing and is returning a true. I have tried and searched a lot of material on replacing and removing the NULL characters, but all were in vain.
This is my parser:

```
char *str="Step1";
fp=fopen(fname, "rb");
if(NULL == fp)
    return(-1);
while(fgets(temp, 400, fp)!= NULL) 
{
    if((strstr(temp, str1))!= NULL)
        {
            system("start Step1.bat");
            count_step[0]++;
        }
}
if(fp)
   fclose(fp);
```

This is how my text file looks like:

```
NULLNULLNULLNULLStep1NULLNULLNULL
NULLNULLStep1
```

Kindly suggest me a quick solution that I can incorporate

Comment: If the file is a text file, why are you opening it in binary mode? That might prevent `fgets` to work properly. And if the file isn't actually a text file, and the `NULL` you show us is actually binary zeroes, then you can't use text functions like `fgets` or `strstr`. Can you please clarify?

Comment: It would be good if you don't use string functions and write your own customised `strstr`. That way, you can handle NULL chars or any other chars as you wish.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I just checked by opening it in binary mode if it makes any difference. Yes it is a text file

Comment: Okay, then you need to tell us what's wrong with the code you have. If a line you read contains the string in `str1` then the condition will be true, so I don't really see what your problem is. When you say the file contains `NULL` characters, do mean the literal string `"NULL"` or the null character `'\0'`? Can you perhaps edit your question to include a hex-dump of the file?

Comment: As @Abhineet mentioned, it is sometimes better to write your own customized function for particular behaviour, especially for something as trivial as strstr

Comment: @JoachimPileborg My text file is written by some other program which also writes some hexadecimal characters in the file. and they show up like NULL in my text file, with these characters I am not able to find my string in the file. No not the literal string 'NULL' but the null hexadecimal characters like '/x00', '/x0a'

Comment: @Abhineet OK I will try that, but even strstr should work right!

Comment: Then the file might indeed be binary, and you can't use string functions like `strstr`, because the `'\0'` characters is the string terminator character and if there is one of those before the string you search for you won't ever find it.

Comment: `strstr` will not work here as it only searches for a substring till it finds a NULL char. The way your file is written is not purely string. For example, if your file would have been a text file, it would be something like this `SPACESPACESPACEStep1SPACESPACESPACE` as you can't write a NULL in text file.

Comment: Writing `strstr` would be best for you. Read your file in binary mode, 1 byte at a time, if the char read is NULL, just move on to read next char. Keep doing this till you find your substring and end the program when you find EOF char.

Comment: @naruto: the "null" character is \0 (or \x00, which is another way of writing a 0.) \x0a is not a null character. It's a newline. And there is no such thing as a "hexadecimal" character; all characters are coded as small integers, and you can write the integer in hex if you want to. For example, a lower case "a" is coded as 97, or \0x61.

Comment: @rici thanks for information :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is binary you can't use string handling functions like `fgets` or `strstr`.

One possible (and slow) solution is to read a chunk of data using [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) then search for the "string" using [`memcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp) on all the data in the file. As a very simple optimization, look for the first byte in the string first, and then use `memcmp`.

Other solutions might include search trees like [a *trie*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).